# TypeError: replaceAll is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jest

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em Electron que funciona bem, mas ao rodar os testes no Jest eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
 console.error
    Error: Uncaught [TypeError: value.replaceAll is not a function]
        at reportException (C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\VisualData\pdv\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\helpers\runtime-script-errors.js:62:24)
        at innerInvokeEventListeners (C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\VisualData\pdv\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:333:9)
        at invokeEventListeners (C:\Users\rafae\Desktop\VisualData\pdv\node_modules\jsdom\lib\jsdom\living\events\EventTarget-impl.js:274:3)
        ...
```

O meu código é o seguinte:

```
let index = 0;
const value = 'Alguma string';
return value.replaceAll('.', match => index++ === 0 ? match : '');
```

Estou utilizando a versão 26.0.1 do Jest e 14.5.4 do Node. O Electron é a versão 11.4.7, Chrome 87.0.4280.141.

- Por que esse problema ocorre se no meu sistema está funcionando bem?
- Como posso consertar isso no Jest sem usar `.replace` com RegExp?

Comment: Rafael, não estão trocados os parâmetros? o regex/match deveria vir primeiro eu acho.. veja a documentação: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll

Comment: A sintaxe é `const newStr = str.replaceAll(regexp|substr, newSubstr|function)`. No caso eu usei `str.replaceAll(substr, function)`, onde `substr` é a string a ser substituída pela função. A função substitui todos os pontos `.` com exceção do primeiro, por isso o `index++ === 0`. Não usei RegExp.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## O problema

Esse problema acontece porque o [`String.prototype.replaceAll`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-string-replaceall) é um método novo, adicionado no ES2021. Além de navegadores antigos, versões mais antigas do Node.js (v14 ou anterior) não suportam esse método, e é por isso que o teste no Jest falha.

Você pode ver a tabela de suporte de navegadores no [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_string_replaceall):

[image: Tabela do Can I Use]

O *shim* desse método pode ser obtido no pacote [string.prototype.replaceall](https://github.com/es-shims/String.prototype.replaceAll).

## A solução

### Suporte para navegadores

Para permitir que navegadores executem esse código sem problema, é necessário realizar o polyfill, incluindo o *shim* e executando o método `.shim()` uma única vez.

1. Instale o pacote como uma dependência do projeto com `npm i string.prototype.replaceall` ou `yarn add string.prototype.replaceall`;
2. Adicione o *polyfill*:

```js
import replaceAllInserter from 'string.prototype.replaceall';

replaceAllInserter.shim();
```

### Suporte para o Node.js e Jest

#### Atualizar o Node.js

Caso seja possível atualizar o Node.js, você pode atualizá-lo para uma versão mais recente, que utilize a [versão 8.5 do V8](https://v8.dev/blog/v8-release-85), que é quando o `.replaceAll` foi implementado.

De acordo com a [lista disponível no site do Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/), nenhuma versão utiliza o V8 8.5, mas a partir do Node.js 15.0.0 é utilizada a versão 8.6 do V8. Então, atualize o Node.js para v15 ou superior.

#### Utilizar o polyfill em desenvolvimento

Como no Electron está funcionando, já que a versão 87 do Chrome já possui a implementação do método, você pode utilizar o *polyfill* apenas no ambiente de desenvolvimento, conforme mencionado [nessa *issue*](https://github.com/testing-library/dom-testing-library/issues/797#issuecomment-843175877).

1. Instale o pacote como uma dependência de desenvolvimento com `npm i -D string.prototype.replaceall` ou `yarn add -D string.prototype.replaceall`;
2. Modifique a sua configuração do Jest, adicionando um novo arquivo na propriedade `setupFilesAfterEnv`:

```js
{
  "jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": ["<rootDir>/jestSetup.js"]
  }
}
```

3. No arquivo `jestSetup.js`, adicione o código do *polyfill*:

```js
import replaceAllInserter from 'string.prototype.replaceall';

replaceAllInserter.shim();
```